# Handling realtime data sync between microservices with rabbitmq queues

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, microservices, devops, eventual-consistency

We have setup our microservice to use `rabbitmq` queues to process any upcoming data.

So, we have `service A`, `service B`, `service C` and `service D`.

When request comes to create a user to `service A`, it creates a user and pushed an event to `newUserIsCreated` queue.

Now, `service B` and `service C` needs to update their database for the newly added user.

---

*Problem*:

What if user creation fails in any `service B` and `service C`.

Possible failure scenarios can be validation failure, or `service B` and `service C` is down.

There is also issue if `service D` tries to access the same user.

What would `service B` and `service C` response with? Because by then they won't have the newly created user.

---

To sum up,

How to handle validation failure or any kind of failure between these services?

What to do if real-time syncing is required? (queues might take time to be processed)

Comment: I think for your use case, instead of rabbitmq you should have another `service-x` which calls three other service incase if anyone of the service is down or not responding your `service-x` should be able to perform rollback operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have `B` and `C` (and any other service which needs to acknowledge that the user is created) publish an acknowledgement message to RabbitMQ to be picked up by `A`; `A` then does not acknowledge the user was created until it receives the acknowledgements.  This is not foolproof: there's every chance that it succeeded everywhere but `A` didn't get the acknowledgements in time.  For that (ideally rare) situation, you can have a process to clean up.

It's worth noticing though, that this sort of synchronous relation is basically reimplementing request/response via a message queue, so if going down this path, why not just do direct request/response (e.g. HTTP or gRPC)?

If you have an operation which needs to affect multiple services, it's often useful to model it as a saga, which will make requests to the various services and handle failures (and potentially give up if there have been too many failures, rolling back the changes it's made).  By persisting the state of the saga (e.g. updated `B`, but `C` has not yet acknowledged the update), it can be queried.

If you find that most operations in `B` are part of sagas touching `A`, then it may be worth considering whether `B` and `A` should be the same service, which would enable stronger consistency guarantees and also likely simplify things.

Comment: This is a solid answer.  I would add that for a somewhat similar application we had where periodic disconnects were a fact of life, we created a "ConsistencyAudit" microservice (separately) that subscribed to `...created` events from multiple services and watched for any misses, then took some action to notify an admin.  Easy, separate, performant, and (as it turned out) unnecessary, but was built for similar concerns.

Comment: Yeah, in a more event-sourced system, that's what I'd go for.